# AWS API Gateway custom domain path configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

After a day of studying I am still confused with how to correctly configure a custom domain to AWS API Gateway so I can use the same custom domain for multiple APIs.

So I have already deployed my custom domain `api.my-domain.com` and obtained a ACM certificate. I created CNAME to point `api.my-domain.com` to the `API Gateway domain name` and can access it.

However, I am confused how to configure "API mappings". According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-mappings.html?icmpid=apigateway_console_help, I can use different path (which is also called "ApiMapping key") to route requests to different API endpoints. My current configurations are:

```
API: api1        stage: default        path: path1
API: api2        stage: default        path: path2
```

However, I can not access either APIs. Sending requests to `api.my-domain.com/path1` or `api.my-domain.com/path2` returns a *403 "message": "Missing Authentication Token"* error, sending requests to any other non-existing path will return a *403 "message": "Forbidden"* error.

I am not sure if I misconfigured something, or I am not accessing those APIs with the correct way?

Comment: It sounds like you enabled an authentication setting on the API, and you aren't sending any API credentials in your request.

Comment: No that is not the case. I do have one API requiring API key, but the other does not. And I have included the correct API key in the request.